# Comparing two parts of url using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I want to rewrite url if it is like: subdomain.xxx.com/zzz/NOT_subdomain/fff

so I have something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^([a-z0-9-]+).xxx.com/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)
RewriteCond %1 =!%3 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.xxx.com/404.html
```

But it do rewrite when subdomain and NOT_subdomain are equal, I tried it without ! but did not works... any help?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your condition to:

```
RewriteCond %1//%3 !^(.*)//\1$
```

You can't have **%** backreferences in the right hand side of a condition, so you can put both on the left hand side and use a `\1` to reference the grouping. So `(.*)` groups what is in `%1`, and then `\1` attempts to match what is in `%3` with the grouping. If it fails, then the two are not equal and the condition is true.

So you have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^([a-z0-9-]+).xxx.com/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)
RewriteCond %1//%3 !^(.*)//\1$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.xxx.com/404.html
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks it works. But I want to be sure if I understand it well... you wrote that it can not be on left side... you mean on right? because in your rule it is on left side...
So \1 will be referencing to %1 right? So this should work too then: RewriteCond %1bb%3 !^(.*)bb\1$ am I right? Thanks

Comment: @DusanPlavak yeah, I got my left/right mixed up and yes, that regex should work. The `//` part is just to delimit the %1 and %3